# resConfigs per build type

Tags: android, gradle

How can I override the `resConfigs` per build types? I read that flavors would allow that, but I don't use them. I just want for my debug build another set of supported languges.

Here is what I tried:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resConfigs "de", "en" // allow also german in debug builds
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        resConfigs "en"       // english only releases
    }
}
```

Any simple idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: This ticket might been related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66133

Comment: resConfigs isn't heeded for debug builds anyway, so just leaving resConfigs "en" in your release build should achieve what you want

Comment: No this is wrong @Nilzor this also applies for debug versions. I had to add `"en-RXA", "ar-RXB"` in order to test the pseudo locales.

Comment: Ah you're right I did a mistake in my testing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some reason the individual buildType configs doesn't support the `resConfigs` command as you point out, but `defaultConfig` does and then you can use this trick to manipulate it per build type even without flavors configured:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en"
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("debug")) {
            variant.mergedFlavor.resourceConfigurations.add("de")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Man why didn't I think about to manipulate it on demand. Brilliant idea!

Comment: I just posted this answer to a related question. Might be useful for people who find this question/answer first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259173/android-how-to-reset-resconfigs-for-release-variant/42259174#42259174

Comment: Can I use `variant.mergedFlavor.resourceConfigurations.remove("de")` ? I tried it but not working
@AutonomousApps

Comment: No, I'm actually pretty that doesn't work, although I can't recall why. As an alternative, you could try getting the whole list, manually removing de from this list, clear the resConfigs list (which does work) and then setting your non-de list on it.

Comment: For some reasons when `resConfigs` is defined explicitly updating `resourceConfigurations` didn't work for me. However, if you omit `resConfigs` all together it works

Comment: Pay attention, that Lint rule "MissingTranslation" won't consider "de" locale in that case and won't warn you about missing translation.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. `de` wasn't succesfully added. Doing everything inside the `applicationVariants.all { ... }` lambda works though:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // No resConfigs here!
        // resConfigs "en"
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals("debug")) {
            variant.mergedFlavor.resourceConfigurations.add("de")
        } else {
            variant.mergedFlavor.resourceConfigurations.add("en", "de")
        }
    }
}
```

or in Kotlinscript:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // no resConfigs here!
    }
    android.applicationVariants.all {
        val resConfigs = when {
            name.equals("debug") -> listOf("en", "de")
            else -> "en"
        }
        (mergedFlavor as DefaultProductFlavor).addResourceConfigurations(resConfigs)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `Unresolved reference: DefaultProductFlavor` error. I am using the Android Gradle plugin version 4.0.1. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @PonsuyambuVelladurai try using `AbstractProductFlavor` instead of `DefaultProductFlavor`. This helped me me when I updated to AGP 4.0.0. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103603/how-to-set-different-applicationid-for-each-flavor-combination-using-flavordimen