# Android: How to reset resConfigs for release variant?

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-type

To make development faster, I want to do the following:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en"
    }
}
```

My app has a lot of languages, and doing this saves significant time while developing. However, I do NOT want to release a version with this set. Unfortunately, `resConfigs` is not available on product flavors or build types, so I can't set it in `debug {}`, for example.

**How can I automatically exclude `resConfigs` from *release* variants?** I do not want to have to remember comment out that line of code when I'm building for release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41975113/2740621) to a related question. Here's how you do it:

in **app/build.gradle**

```
// Reset `resConfigs` for release
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('release')) {
            variant.mergedFlavor.@mResourceConfiguration = null
        }
    }
}
```

This works because `mResourceConfiguration` is the backing field for `resConfigs`. Unfortunately, The Android Gradle DSL does not currently expose a method to reset `resConfigs`, so we're forced to access the field directly using the groovy `@<fieldName>` syntax. This works, even though `mResourceConfiguration` is private.

**WARNING**: this solution is a little fragile, as the Android Gradle build tools team could change the name of that field at any time, since it is not part of the public API.

Comment: The solution didn't work for me, were there breaking changes with gradle? `variant.mergedFlavor.resourceConfigurations.clear()` did work though.

Comment: I used this successfully on an older version of the Android Gradle Plugin (AS 2.x). I haven't tried it with AS 3.x and build tools 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't this work?

Detect the debug build, reset the configurations and add your desired debug configuration.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {   
        variant.mergedFlavor.resourceConfigurations.clear()
        variant.mergedFlavor.resourceConfigurations.add("en")
    }
}
```

Comment: `resourceConfigurations` is not a public member of `variant.mergedFlavor`.

Comment: @AutonomousApps Works for me. What Gradle version are you using?

Comment: An old one. Tools 2.1.2 and Gradle 2.14.