# How to set applicationid for different flavor and buildtype?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-build, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-buildconfig

I have

2 flavors

- flavor1
- flavor2

and

5 buildtypes

- dev
- debug
- uat
- preprod
- release

I would like to set full applicationId to be

- com.example.flavor1dev
- com.example.flavor1debug
- com.example.flavor1uat
- com.example.flavor1preprod
- com.example.flavor1
- com.example.flavor2.dev
- com.example.flavor2.debug
- com.example.flavor2.uat
- com.example.flavor2.preprod
- com.example.flavor2

I use kotlin-dsl ,Please help

Comment: Without a Gradle's Task I think it's not possibile. You could set "productFlavors" in build.gradle file providing an "applicationIdSuffix" for each Flavour, but there is nothing about BuildTypes. So you can create "com.example.flavor1" and "com.example.flavor2" automatic ApplicationID, but without BuildType inside it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set different applicationId for each flavor combination using flavorDimensions when using Gradle Kotlin-DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103603/how-to-set-different-applicationid-for-each-flavor-combination-using-flavordimen)

Answer (score 0):

update your build.gradle to below

```
   android {
 
   flavorDimensions "flavors" , "enviornment"

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            dimension "flavors"
             applicationId "com.example.flavor1"
         }
        flavour2 {
            dimension "flavors"
            applicationId "com.example.flavor2"
        }
        dev {
            dimension "enviornment"
            manifestPlaceholders.appName = "(DEV)"
            applicationIdSuffix 'dev'
        }
        debug {
            dimension "enviornment"
            manifestPlaceholders.appName = "(Debug)"
            applicationIdSuffix 'debug'
        }
        uat {
            dimension "enviornment"
            manifestPlaceholders.appName = "(UAT)"
            applicationIdSuffix 'uat'
        }
        preprod {
            dimension "enviornment"
            manifestPlaceholders.appName = "(PreProd)"
            applicationIdSuffix 'preProd'
        }
       release {
            dimension "enviornment"
            manifestPlaceholders.appName = "(your app name)"
        }
    }
}
```